# PCA and K-means separation not precise for my data. What statistical method should I use?

Tags: pca, k-means

I have a data set of 126 different protein parameters(X-variables)and 244 different CD proteins. I wanted test if PCA and K-means clustering could separate my 244 proteins into two different clusters ( Enzymes and binding proteins). Here is my result from PCA and K-means. ( I used their actual function to find out if the separation was accurate or not.

[image][image]
I used K=3 because it was able to cluster the data more accurately than K=2 in k-means. However, the separation is not very accurate. We can see a cluster of enzymes ( 3 on the score plot), but there are many enzymes that are placed into number 2 and 1 clusters and vice versa. In that situation,

1. Are there any methods that could determine how good my model is in predicting the result correctly? It seems to me that is is not very accurate.
2. What kind of statistical method would be appropriate for my data to predict the function of protein, Enzyme or non-enzyme?

Comment: `if PCA and K-means clustering could separate` You mean that you did PCA first and extracted `m` strobgest components and then did k-means on them? If it was so, what was `m`? What is `K` is this `m` or number of clusters `k`?

Comment: I am not very good at symbols because I have not taken linear algebra. Based on what I have read on PCA, I will try to explain your question. So, I have 126 different X variables, hence when I do PCA I have 126 different principle components (m). I selected 2 Principle components for my score plot in the diagram represented above. Then I used k-means clustering to find the cluster in the data where I chose k=3. When I chose  k=2, it was not effective to separate the protein at all.

Comment: `I selected 2 Principle components` Your scree diagram clearly shows that you have to keep at least 3 PCs in order to insure the lion's share of the information from the data. Maybe even 3 to 10 PCs. With 2 PCs you are at great risk to overlook clusters in the data, if they exist.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I also think using 10 PC would be appropriate because it captures about 70% of the data and it exists where there is slight break in scree plot right before it levels out. My question is;     I am looking to plot a scatter-plot where I can use data of score plot from PC1 to PC10, but haven't found a way to plot that. The minitab that I use have scatter plot unit 3D. I know it is hard to represent data in multiple dimension. How can I resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't abuse k-means for classification. It's an *explorative*, not a predictive method.

Instead, train a classifier such as a support vector machine (I would recommend a linear SVM). These methods optimize for prediction accuracy - k-means does not.